# Saving an object which contains arraylists in arraylists

Tags: java

I have an object of type Restaurant called myRestaurant which contains EmployeesAList, MenuAList and OrdersAList, each of which storing instances of objects Employee, Menu_Item and Order. Each instance of Order stores integers, strings and an arraylist of integers.

When I save myRestaurant, every arraylist is saved except for the arraylist which is within the Orders class.

Any suggestions?

save method in Runner

```
 public boolean SaveToFile(Restaurant myrest)
{
    try
    {
        File outFile = new File("etrest.rest");  
        //creates object representing file

        FileOutputStream outFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        //connection between program and file

        ObjectOutputStream outObjectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outFileStream);
        //class which is used to pass objects which will be saved to file

        //Write serializable ArrayList to file
        outObjectStream.writeObject(myrest);        

        //output done, so close the stream
        outObjectStream.close();
        return true;
    }
    catch(IOException IOE)
    {
        System.out.println(IOE.toString()); //debug purpose
        return false;        
    }
}
```

method in Restaurant to add Order

ArrayList OrdersAList = new ArrayList();

```
public void AddOrder(Order o)
{
    OrdersAList.add(o);
}
```

part of order class
ArrayList Menu_ItemsIDAList = new ArrayList();

```
public Order()
{
    paid = false;
    WaiterNo = 0;
    TableNo = 0;
    item = 0;
}

public Order(boolean pd, int wN, int tN, int it)
{
    paid     = pd;
    WaiterNo = wN;
    TableNo  = tN;
    item     = it;
}

//MENU ITEMS ENTERED PER ORDER
public void AddMenu_ItemID(int item)
{
    Menu_ItemsIDAList.add(item);
}
```

when i create an instance of Order I create a loop to populate the Menu_ItemsIDAList

Comment: How do you "save" your myRestaurant object ?

Comment: Code please this is too generic of a question

Comment: should i save from the Resataurant class instead?

Comment: check how the orderlist is connected to the restaurant.. it seems to be missing...

Comment: AND: do not use capitals as the first letter, only for Classes!

Comment: in the Restaurant class, I create an arraylist which stores orders.
i create an instance of restaurant and save in the runner. now in order, i create an arraylist of integers..the latter is the problem

Comment: Make sure the field you intend to write is non-transient and non-static.

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly reconstruct your problem...

You/we should have a better overview where your lists will be saved exactly, and where is your "add"-method? In which class...

So I recommend to you, making a diagram. In your case a UML class diagram (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram).

Once you understand the classes, attributes and relations then you can draw such a diagram and can use the code in a proper way.

Of course we could give you a quick solution that "something is missing"... but for future development you should understand basics of object oriented programming. UML class and UML use case diagrams are a good start too...

Comment: but is the concept correct?
ie. if I have arraylists stored in Restaurant, and one of those arraylists contains an arraylist in it, and i create an instance of restaurant in runner and save/load that instance of restaurant from the runner. when i load, the other attributes of Order are saved; it's just the arraylist which disappears..